# Managed Metadata Field CreateValuesInEditForm Property

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the "CreateValuesInEditForm" Property for a Managed Metadata field from anywhere in the SharePoint Interface or Programmatically using CSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable since [TaxonomyField.CreateValuesInEditForm Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.createvaluesineditform(v=office.14).aspx) is *settable*:

```
public bool CreateValuesInEditForm { get; set; }
```

**Example**

```
using(var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     var field = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(taxFieldName);
     var taxField = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
     taxField.CreateValuesInEditForm = false;
     taxField.Update();
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```